# Android: Organizing Strings and String Arrays in res/values

Tags: android, xml, android-resources

I am working on a project that includes a lot of strings and string arrays. I would like to put them into created folders inside res/values, but I get errors when I try to do this.  Either getRecources() does not recognize the new folder or the xml attributes cannot link together.  I know this is a noob-ish question, but thanks for the help!

Comment: You cannot have subfolders. However you can split your strings and string arrays into multiple files (e.g. strings1.xml, strings2.xml).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't create any subfolders in your `values` folder. But you have two instruments to control the hierarchy.

**String arrays** are declared in the following way:

```
<string-array name="arr_name">
    <item>Text</item>
    <item>Another text</item>
</string-array>
```

You can access them through `R.array.arr_name`.

**Prefixes** are kind of obvious, but since you mentioned that you are a novice, it's worth mentioning. I usually prefix all of my strings depending on how they are used. For example, *btn_* for the text used on buttons, *dialog_* for strings used in dialogs and so on. This way autocomplete in the IDE also works much better too.

Also you can split your declarations into different files, but this doesn't have any impact at all on the way you access them, so I don't know if this can help you.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I have started to find myself doing.  Thanks again for the help. Greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can define array of strings using following way. Later you can access it in code with R.values.langs

```
<string-array name="langs">
    <item>бг</item>
    <item>en</item>
    <item>ру</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 0):

To organise my res folder I use defined xml files not sub-folders.

Basic Example:
- if you have Strings for your Login Page put them in login_strings.xml
- if you have Strings for your Options Page put them in options_strings.xml
etc.

Hope this helps.